# Recovering cosh(ax) from it's fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, contour-integration

Let's say $f(x)=\cosh(ax)$, where $a$ is a complex number and $x$ is real. Then the fourier transform is $F(\omega)=\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega-ia)+\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega+ia)$. So it's the sum of two dirac deltas that take their nonzero values at the complex numbers $z=\pm ia$. Now lets say we blindly take the inverse fourier transform. $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{i \omega x}d \omega=0$, since we just integrated along the real line and the dirac deltas take their nonzero values somewhere in the complex plane. What went wrong? Are we supposed to use some kind of contour? What contour are we supposed to use?

Comment: The usual definition of the Fourier transform only defines the Fourier transform on tempered distributions. I am pretty sure that $\cosh$ does not define a tempered distribution. Also, the (pointwise) inversion formula has prerequisites which are not satisfied here.